# SpringBoot 3 - Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

The configuration was working for SpringBoot2. Entity Manager Factory not getting initiated

Also seeing these errors

> Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: dataSource or dataSourceClassName
> or jdbcUrl is required.
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: dataSource or
> dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.repository"} )
public class DataSourceConfiguration {

    @Bean("dataSource")
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource()
    {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name="jdbcTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate dwJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) throws URISyntaxException {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.entity");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(false);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
        return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            @Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory
                    entityManagerFactory
    ) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager=new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);

        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your properties file?

Comment: spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/user_management
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

Comment: Typo in @Qualifier("DataSource"). Should be @Qualifier("dataSource"). And in @Bean(name="JdbcTemplate") should be @Bean(name="jdbcTemplate")

Comment: still facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Try using picking of properties using the **Environment** class and set the values in **DriverManagerDataSource**.It's a Simple implementation of the standard JDBC DataSource interface, configuring the plain old JDBC DriverManager via bean properties, and returning a new Connection from every getConnection call.

One demerit of this class - doesn't provides connection pooling facility so not recommended for Production. For this you can integrate Hikari Pooling mechanism which is default DB Pool mechanism for Spring-Data.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {
    "com.xxx", "com.yyy", "com.zzz" }, entityManagerFactoryRef = "dbEntityManager", transactionManagerRef = "dbTransactionManager")
public class DataSourceConfiguration {

@Autowired
private Environment env;

@Bean(name = "datasource")
@Primary
public DataSource dbDataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));
    return dataSource;
}

/**
* Implemented Hikari Pool mechanism
* @Bean(name = "datasource")
* @Primary
* public DataSource dbDataSource() {
*       final HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
*       final HikariDataSource dataSource;
*       config.setPoolName("HikariPool");
*       config.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url") ); 
*       config.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username") );
*       config.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));
*       config.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"));
*       config.setMaximumPoolSize(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize"));
*       config.setMaxLifetime(840000);
*       dataSource = new HikariDataSource(config);
* }
*/

@Primary
@Bean(name = "dbTransactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager dbTransactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(dbEntityManager().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
    }
}

@Primary
@Bean(name = "dbEntityManager")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean dbEntityManager() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(dbDataSource());
    em.setPackagesToScan(
            new String[] { "com.xxx", "com.yyy", "com.zzz" });
    em.setPersistenceUnitName("dbEntityManager");
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    return em;
}

@Bean(name = "jdbcTemplate")
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate1(@Qualifier("datasource") DataSource ds) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(ds);
}
```

Comment: thanks Mohit. How to integrate Hikari Pooling mechanism in Spring Boot 3. In Spring Boot 2 you can manually integrate. I'm not sure if thats the option in Spring Boot 3.

Comment: I think it will work in the same way as it was earlier, in 3.0 release note they have not mentioned any changes related to Hikari Pool. Just uncomment the hikari pool section in the code and give it a try.